# launch vscode script from powershell prompt

Tags: python, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

[Attempted to use the commands as suggested by others in the comment, no results or change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9wYF.png)I have switched from CommandPrompt to Powershell and want to use the same command I used in Command prompt to open the file I'm working on in VSCode, i.e.:
`code .`
In Powershell, this doesn't launch VSCode or really do anything noticeable. Would love some insights. Thanks.

Comment: `code .` should work the same in PowerShell as it does in `cmd.exe`. What does `Get-Command code -All` report? If there are multiple results, the first one is the effective one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I ran the ```Get-Command code -All``` line, and got back ```code.cmd``` and ```code```. I tried the first command, and nothing happened. VSCode didn't launch.

Comment: It works, both of `code.cmd` and `code`, could you attach a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. This will open the current folder on which you triggered powershell.

```
Start-Process code .
```

As  @Steven already mentioned, it should also work by just typing `code` on your powershell input.

Comment: I have tried all three of these suggestions to no avail. VSCode does not start up after inputting any of these commands. I guess it would be helpful at this point to mention that I had to switch to Powershell from CommandPrompt because CommandPrompt will no longer launch on my laptop.